# Python 2 Trying to launch an exe from current users appdata folder

Tags: windows, python-2.x

I'm trying to write a kodi addon using python 2. the location to the exe is in the users local appdata folder. I've written one that works but it needs the users name in the path. I'd like to be able to create the path using the current users username.

I'm new to coding so please be kind.

Comment: The current user's local application data directory is `os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA']`.

Comment: Thanks I've done that and got the area What i want to do is it add it to a path, e.g path = os.envrion['localappdata'] to the path to the exe so if tried things like (path)\\"then the path that follows"\\file.exe

Comment: hi. It's working now. I was using path.join(path1),(path2) changed it to path.join((path1),(path2)) and i now get both variables as a full path.